# How to check if a datefield is expired (Laravel/Lumen)

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, timestamp, compare

I have a table called events and events expire. if their dates and time is up how do i check in my controller if the dateTime field from and to are up if that event time is up i want to set the expired field to 1

```
public function up()
{
Schema::create(‘club_events’, function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments(‘id’);
$table->string(‘event_name’);
$table->string(‘description’);
$table->boolean(‘special_events’);
$table->decimal(‘event_price’);
$table->dateTime(‘from’)->nullable();
$table->dateTime(‘to’)->nullabe();
$table->boolean(‘expired’)->nullable();

$table->integer(‘club_id’)->unsigned();
$table->timestamps();

$table->foreign(‘club_id’)
->references(‘id’)->on(‘club’)
->onDelete(‘cascade’);

});
}
```

Comment: Unless you have good use for the expired field, the 'to' field is enough to determine if the event is expired.

Comment: @Gookcake Understood.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would compare it to the current datetime like:

```
if (now()->gte($clubEvent->to)) {
    // the event is expired
} else {
    // not expired
}
```

Here are the Carbon [comparison](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison) functions.

Update the expired field like:

```
$clubEvent->update([
     'expired' => now()->gte($clubEvent->to)
]);
```